# Some Question about Security Proof of authenticated identity-based encryption

Tags: identity-based-encryption

In [authenticated identity-based encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2002/072) by Benn Lynn, in proof of security, I have a little difficulties in understanding.
In key extraction queries,if attacker request for guessed ID, then B fails. I think this is because B cannot generate private key for guessed ID.
 When attacker challenges messages M0,M1 and two identities, if identities are not guessed ID, then B fails.
In this scenario, I think B cannot encrypt for guessed ID as it does not know private key. However, here, it fails when identities are not guessed ID.
Please guide me correct thinking.